Fast ways to Sha256 hash each line in file text
I use this code
import os
import hashlib

with open('plain_text.txt') as f: # Plain text
    for line in f.readlines():
        line = line.rstrip("\n")
        m = hashlib.sha256((line).encode('utf-8'))
        os.system(f'echo {m.hexdigest()} >> sha256_file.txt') # Hexadecimal file

I want to accelerate the process of hash each line in file text or if any other method to make the same process faster
Find another method to make the same process faster.

This question is similar to: How do I parallelize a simple Python loop?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This reads as a homework assignment

Right now, you are spawning a new shell process to append the SHA256 hashes to your sha256_file.txt for each individual hash. Depending on the length of each line, this will likely take much longer than the hash calculation itself.
Thus, you should instead write to the file directly from Python, e.g. as follows:
import os
import hashlib

with open('plain_text.txt', 'r') as f:
  with open('sha256_file.txt', 'a') as sha256_file:
    for line in f:
      line = line.rstrip("\n")
      hexdigest = hashlib.sha256(line.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
      print(hexdigest, file=sha256_file)


don't read the file as utf-8 text just to encode it back to utf-8 bytes.  read it as bytes in the first place.
